# A lot of tcp window update size segments

Tags: websocket, tcp

I am testing websocket communication by sending small messages (180 bytes) per 15 milliseconds. I always get for some time (10 or 21 seconds) big delay (even 250 milliseconds). I checked it in wireshark and i saw that for this specific seconds i got a lot of tcp window update segments. Like on this screen.

[image]

It is little strange because Calculated window size is pretty big (about 258944 bytes). Example time for communication:

[image]

If i increase message size i dont have this problem and i dont get this segments.

[image]

Comment: Looks like packet loss and hence congestion control to me.  Note that all the packets marked "window updates" by Wireshark are ACKing 67993 (while SLE and SRE are indicating it has received data well past that).  In packet 2929 67993 is finally retransmitted, but marked as "out of order" indicating that Wireshark never saw that transmitted before.  So maybe the capture is incomplete as well.

Comment: Why i didn't get normal 'DUP ACK'  instead window update segments? Why is my tcp window increased when size is pretty big? I have never got any full window size segment.

Comment: I don't know the precise definition used by Wireshark for duplicate acks.  It is plausible that they are not considered duplicate because the window and SRE are changing. The window size is increasing most likely because the app is consuming data from the RECV queue.

Comment: I also note that the window size went from 62K to 82K in a small amount of time, indicating that the app read about 20K bytes over that time interval, which is a large number of 180 byte messages.  Perhaps the app was a slow consumer now catching up, possibly because it is a java app that needed to GC.

Comment: Further, note that the SEQ is increasing pretty fast in the "window updates," but we don't see any of the data arriving, which is strange.